# How to stack multiple multivariate timeseries and save it in the form of .pth files?

Tags: tensorflow, forecasting, ieee

I am trying to implement the REGENN code as [this link](https://github.com/gabrielspadon/ReGENN) for my battery parameter dataset,

The default dataset used in the code is accessible [here](https://github.com/gabrielspadon/ReGENN/tree/master/data/BRA-WTH%20(Y3)).

A sample of the dataset I am trying to use:

```
    Date    Time    Battery Level   Temperature Voltage Current Status
2   01-09-2020  19:55:47    100 30.3    4357    375213  Discharging
3   01-09-2020  19:55:47    100 30.3    4357    561981  Discharging
4   01-09-2020  19:55:48    100 30.3    4357    501251  Discharging
5   01-09-2020  19:55:48    100 30.3    4357    599670  Discharging
6   01-09-2020  19:55:49    100 30.3    4357    738831  Discharging
7   01-09-2020  19:55:49    100 30.3    4357    522308  Discharging
8   01-09-2020  19:55:50    100 30.3    4357    357208  Discharging
9   01-09-2020  19:55:51    100 30.3    4357    278015  Discharging
10  01-09-2020  19:55:51    100 30.3    4357    379028  Discharging
```

REGENN requires two or more multivariate time series stacked together with dimensions of [no. of variables within each time series which is common in all the time series considered (i.e all the time series have the same number and same type of variables logged over the same timestamps), the timestamps, no of multivariate time series].

A sample of this can be seen in Fig.1 of [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9416768).

So, How to convert these datasets in the form of stacked multivariate time series and save the same in the form of .pth file format?